# iText RTF - Text leading on footer doesn't work

Tags: java, itext, footer, rtf

I want to have text inside footer with leading -1, but my code doesen't work (If I add same phrase inside body of word and footer, text leading on body shows correctly but text leading on footer not).

Here my code:

```
BaseFont hbf = BaseFont.createFont("/Fonts/arial.ttf", BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
Font fontArialHeaderFooter = new Font(hbf, 8, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK);

Phrase foot = new Phrase(
        "_________________________________________________________________________________________________________",
        fontArialHeaderFooter);
//Position of page number with \t
Phrase textFoot = new Phrase(
        "Carrer de la XXXX, 2\r\nXXXXX Barcelona\r\nTel. XX XXX XX XX\r\nFax. XX XXX XX XX\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t       ",
        fontArialHeaderFooter);

foot.setLeading(-1);
textFoot.setLeading(-1);
foot.add(textFoot);

//Add Phrase on footer with page number (attribute "true")
HeaderFooter footer = new HeaderFooter(foot, true);
word.setFooter(footer);

//Add same Phrase inside body of word document to compare body with footer
word.add(foot);
```

Result here:
[image: http://gyazo.com/14e94a3297b273a91af8a5e5bf88b84f.png]

Why doesn't the footer show leading correctly, and how can I fix it?

Comment: iText has abandoned RTF in December 2009. The functionality you're using is no longer supported.